# Follow redirects with AngleSharp to localhost

Tags: c#, anglesharp

I have an integration test for code flow in our authentication process (we use IdentityServer).

This requires us:

1. Initiate auth: open the first link http://domain1 which redirects to external provider http://provider with UI.
2. Enter credentials and submit the form. This action will redirect us back to http://domain1/externallogincallback which itself should redirect to http://domain2 as it is configured in IdentityServer. Since we use code flow it includes query string `?code=...` in the url
3. Verify that `code` is received and is valid.

To perform all these actions we use AngleSharp which is working great. It follows all redirects to external provider, we can fill in the form and submit it.
But since it is an integration test - we don't have up and running client for http://domain2 so it is configured in code as http://localhost - which will show nothing if you navigate to it, but it is okey for manual testing in browser because after all the redirects we can see the final url where we can find the `code` that we need to validate.
The problem comes with AngelSharp on the last step: it returns null document since there is no service under http://localhost, so we can't even check `document.DocumentUri` for our `code` query string.

Is there a way to track all the redirects from the main context and see the last url it is being redirected to (non existing page)?

PS: using Selenium it is working well since it is using different approach and can provide context for non existing pages, but it is extremely slow, so I would like to stay with AngleSharp

**EDIT 1:**
Here is the code example that I use:

```
var redirectResponse = await _client.Get(_redirectUrl);
var stringRedirectResponse = await redirectResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var filtered = new List<Request>();
var config = Configuration.Default
    .WithRequesters()
    .WithJs()
    .WithMetaRefresh()
    .WithDefaultLoader(new LoaderOptions
    {
        IsResourceLoadingEnabled = true,
        Filter = request =>
        {
            lock (filtered)
            {
                filtered.Add(request);
            }
            
            return !request.Address.Href.StartsWith(_finalRedirectUri);
        }
    })
    .WithJs()
    .WithPersistentCookies(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\anglesharp.cookies")
    ;
var browsingContext = BrowsingContext.New(config);
var document = await browsingContext
    .OpenAsync(res => 
        res.Content(stringRedirectResponse)
            .Address(redirectResponse.RequestMessage.RequestUri)
            .Status(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            )
    ;
var inputUsernameElement = document.QuerySelector<IHtmlInputElement>("input[name=username]");
inputUsernameElement.Value = _username;

var newDocument = await inputUsernameElement.SubmitAsync();
var uri = new Uri(document.DocumentUri);
return HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("code");
```

Comment: Yes that is possible. Essentially, you can have a filter on the requester and just change the desired target URL. See, e.g., (sorry its a test, but it gives you the idea): https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/blob/master/src/AngleSharp.Core.Tests/Library/HttpRequester.cs#L327. Would that work for you?

Comment: @FlorianRappl thanks for your reply, I tried your example and in filtered collection I have some urls, but not all of them. Please look at my changes in the question, I added code example. Filter predicate adds strange behaviour - it stops on the fire redirect after submit. If I remove Filter predicate the `newDocument` variable will be null. I am confused